# Key input without pressing enter? (LINUX)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, input

So i'm trying to make something that waits for a user to press a key, and it stores whatever key they pressed in a variable without pressing enter. I heard of mscvrt but that only works on Windows, but i'm trying to make this on linux. Any ideas?

Comment: Why the big LINUX in the title? Do you have any reason whatsoever to think this would be different across platforms?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sadly, the OS does matter here. Direct terminal reads of a single character (without waiting for a newline to be entered) are surprisingly non-portable (see answers to duplicate question).